# composing colormaps in matplotlib using elements like tab* builtin

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

I am trying to plot some colorful discrete data using `matplotlib`.
With `tab10-like` colormaps I get nice results

[image]

However, I would need a combination of tab20 and tab20b parts, to have my data plotted as:

```
1->tab20darkblue
2->tab20lightblue
3->tab20cOrange1
4->tab20cOrange2
5->tab20cOrange3
6->tab20cOrange4
```

is that possible somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a `ListedColormap` from the colors of other colormaps.

E.g to get the darkorange color from the `tab20c` colormap, use `plt.cm.tab20c(4)` (as this is the 5th color in that map). Note that this works only for indexed colormaps - otherwise you need to use a value between 0 and 1.

From a list of thus obtained colors, you can create a new `ListedColormap`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors
import numpy as np

colors = [plt.cm.tab20(0),plt.cm.tab20(1),plt.cm.tab20c(4),
          plt.cm.tab20c(5),plt.cm.tab20c(6),plt.cm.tab20c(7)]

cmap=matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(colors)

x = np.arange(1,7)

plt.scatter(x,x,c=x, s=100, cmap=cmap, vmin=1, vmax=7)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Or, to get a nice colorbar as well,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors
import numpy as np

colors = [plt.cm.tab20(0),plt.cm.tab20(1),plt.cm.tab20c(4),
          plt.cm.tab20c(5),plt.cm.tab20c(6),plt.cm.tab20c(7)]

cmap=matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(colors)
norm = matplotlib.colors.BoundaryNorm(np.arange(1,8)-0.5,len(colors))

x = np.arange(1,7)

sc = plt.scatter(x,x,c=x, s=100, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
plt.colorbar(sc, ticks=x)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: great. In the meantime I had found about ListedColormap, but I did not realize I could use the builtins to define the listed Color. Thanks again